# Drawable not drawn fully in canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have created a bitmap and drawn text/drawables on it. Then I have drawn into bitmap using new canvas. I'm doing the same for number of bitmaps which is drawn parallelly in separate threads and once the bitmaps are drawn , it is added to a map which contains list of bitmaps to be drawn on canvas. Finally i take the bitmaps from map and draw them into canvas. But some of my drawables drawn on bitmap are not fully drawn. Any idea why it happens ?

I have drawn drawable like this:

```
    canvas.save();
    canvas.clipRect(left,  top, right, bottom);
    drawable.setBounds(left, top,right, bottom);
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
```

And bitmap is drawn as :

```
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);
```

Comment: `Drawable#setBounds()` method takes "left, top, right, bottom", not "left, right, top, bottom"

Comment: @pskink yeah i have edited it

Comment: so run the code again - this time with left, top, right, bottom

Comment: @pskink Still the same

Comment: @pskink It is an svg image . The left, top, right, bottom points are also calculated correctly.. There is some problem with drawing bitmaps in different threads . It is not invalidated properly. Don't know the exact cause

Comment: i used 10 background parallel threads and it works just fine